# In what context did Joyce Rachelle say this quote?

Tags: quote-source, joyce-rachelle

I often see this quote from Joyce Rachelle being posted: “Don't be afraid to make mistakes. But if you do, make new ones. Life is too short to make the wrong choice twice.”

I was wondering if anyone knows when she said it? Or in what context? Was it a speech? One of her books?